# Return result to opening android application

Tags: android, android-activity

My android app is opened from another app.
I know how to return results to activity,
But what happens when i need to return to the opening app?
Opening app (startActivityForResult) > my app > activity A > activity B > activity C > opening app.
Thanks,
Sharon.

Comment: Huh? Try explaining that more clearly. What is the "opening app"? What component of the "opening app" starts the `Activity` in your app? Did you write the "opening app" yourself (if not, how does it know to use `startActivityForResult(...)`?

Comment: The opening app is any app that may use my app.
No, I didn't write the opening app.
The opening app calls my apps main activity with some extras.
I think it's the same situation when you need to return result not to the calling activity but to an activity further up the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either call `startActivity()` on the opening app again to pass the results *or* call `finish()` in each of the intermediate Activities' `onActivityResult()` methods to cascade the results back down to the opening app.

Comment: If I understand correctly,
1st option, the opening app will pass an extra with activity path that i can open when finished.
2nd option, each intermediate activity will override onActivityResult and simply call finish()?

Comment: Yes, I would try the second option first. The first option probably won't _restart_ the opening app, not _resume_ where the user was.

Comment: OK, I tried the first option and it works great.
Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I only now see your comment.
You mean that 1st will restart the opening app?
I was thinking about a dedicated result activity in the opening app.
But the 2nd option will be more convenient for the opening app,
As the whole cycle can be handled from the same activity instance.
I will try 2nd option too.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm understanding what you do need.
Let me try to explain:

**Main Activity:**

```
//calling your activity from which you expect a result
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForRsult(intent, 0);
```

**Activity B:**

When you finish this one you must do something like,

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK); //This line will do the trick ;)
finish();
```

Back to your `MainActivity` you must `Override` the `onActivityResult()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int arg0, int arg1, Intent arg2) {
    super.onActivityResult(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    if (arg0 == 0) {
        switch (arg1) {
        case RESULT_OK:
               /**DO YOUR CODE HERE.*/
        break;

        default:
        break;
        }
    }
};
```

Let me know about your progress.

Comment: You are talking about the regular case when you start single activity for result.
This is not my question.